# How to convert Arrow Function to Class in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to react.js. I need to implement constructor and more functions which I am aware in Class. So below are the code I want to convert Arrow function to Class. Please help I am very very new to React.js

```
    const CreateArea = () => {

          const [content, setContent] = useState('')


          function onSubmit(e){
            e.preventDefault()

            var date = moment().utcOffset('+05:30').format('hh:mm A DD-MM-YYYY');

            firebase.firestore().collection('qna').add(
            {
              title: "James",
              content,
              time: new Date(),
              time2: date,
              status: "0"
            })
            .then(() => {
              setContent('')
              swal({
                title: "Question Submitted!",
                text: "Your Question is waiting for Approval.",
                icon: "success",
                button: "Close",
                });
            })
          }

          return (
            <div id="footer">
              <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <textarea
                  name="content"
                  onChange={e => setContent(e.currentTarget.value)}
                  value={content}
                  placeholder="Enter Your Question"
                  rows="2"
                  required
                />
                <button></button>

              </form>

            </div>
          );

        }
```

something like this Class

```
class CreateArea extends React.Component {

    // Some Code ....

    }
```

Comment: FWIW, all of the functionality in React class components is now available in React functional components, thanks to the addition of hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
const [content, setContent] = useState('')
```

with

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {content: ''};
}
```

Replace

```
setContent('');
```

with

```
this.setState({content: ''})
```

and to access it, use `this.state.content`

Put your return function inside a render():

```
render() { 
    return ( 
        <div id="footer">
        ....
    );
}
```

Every function needs to be called with this now, for example:

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, to convert your function component in a class component you have to initialize the state with `this.state` and then declare a render function that will actually display the content, as in the following example:

```
class CreateArea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      test: "test"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        content here
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would look like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class CreateArea extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            content: ''
        };
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var date = moment().utcOffset('+05:30').format('hh:mm A DD-MM-YYYY');

        firebase.firestore().collection('qna').add(
            {
                title: 'James',
                this.state.content,
                time: new Date(),
                time2: date,
                status: '0'
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.setState({content: ''});
                swal({
                    title: 'Question Submitted!',
                    text: 'Your Question is waiting for Approval.',
                    icon: 'success',
                    button: 'Close',
                });
            });
    }

    render(): React.ReactNode {
        return (<div id="footer">
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <textarea
                    name="content"
                    onChange={e => this.setState({content: e.currentTarget.value})}
                    value={this.state.content}
                    placeholder="Enter Your Question"
                    rows="2"
                    required
                />
                <button></button>

            </form>

        </div>);

    }
}
```

The most important details are to set the state in the constructor, add the render method and replace `setContent` calls to `setState`.

Comment: Thank you, It worked. But need to change `content` to `this.state.content` as mentioned by @HermitCrab